# Select Box Appears/Disappears on Button Click

Tags: javascript, html

Searched around and couldn't find what I was looking for.  I have 2 buttons that pull up a two different select boxes on a click and they will disappear with a second click.  However, I want select box 1 to disappear on Button click 2 and vice versa: select box 2 will disappear on Button click 1.

HTML:

```js
window.onload = function() 
   { 
      document.getElementById('name1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('name2').style.display = 'none';
   };


   function button1function(id){

      if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none'){
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'initial';
      }else{
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
      }
      }
   function button2function(id){
      if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none'){
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'initial';
      }else{
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
      }
      }
```

```html
<button type="button" value='hide/show' onclick="button1function('name1')">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" value='hide/show' onclick="button2function('name2')">Button 2</button>

    <select id="name1">
     <option value="">What would you like to know..</option>
    </select>
    <select id="name2">
     <option value="">What would you like to know 2..</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/o3btLkpd/

try calling this at the top of the event handler for button 1:

```
document.getElementById('name2').style.display = 'none';
```

and this in the handler for button 2:

```
document.getElementById('name1').style.display = 'none';
```

the full resulting code would be like this:

```
  window.onload = function() { 
    document.getElementById('name1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('name2').style.display = 'none';
  };


  function button1function(id) {
    document.getElementById('name2').style.display = 'none';
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
       document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'initial';
    } else {
     document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  function button2function(id) {
    document.getElementById('name1').style.display = 'none';
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
       document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'initial';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Worked beautifully.  Thanks!